# ESLint and Prettier conflict in WebStorm

Tags: eslint, webstorm, prettier

In my project we use both ESLint and Prettier for code and seems they conflict with each other.

Here is the Prettier configuration in `.prettierrc` file :

```json
{
  "endOfLine": "auto",
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "printWidth": 120,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.scss",
      "options": {
        "singleQuote": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is a part of ESLint in `.eslintrc.json` file:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*",
    "*.d.ts"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "html",
    "import",
    "simple-import-sort",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "airbnb-typescript/base"
      ],
      "rules": {
        
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.component.html",
        "*.container.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ]
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.component.ts",
        "*.container.ts"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Prettier should be used with all files while the ESLint should be used with html, js and ts.

Here are the configs from the settings:

[image: Prettier]

[image: ESLint]

Please help with the final configuration so that everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the official recipes at https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html, namely, use the [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) to turn the conflicting ESLint rules off, and then set up Prettier as your default code formatter in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Prettier**